# What keyboard layout allows me to type ç?

Tags: keyboard-layout

On my Windows machine, I use USA International with deadkeys, and I have no problem typing `ç` (<kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>). However, on my Ubuntu machine, I set my layout to "USA - International (with dead keys) and that key combination returns `ć`. How can I have it return a C with a cedilla rather than an acute accent?

Comment: i think Frances

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using keyboard layout "USA - intl (AltGr dead keys)", I can get ç or Ç by pressing:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>: `ç`
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>: `Ç`

Comment: I prefer dead keys. Is there a way to get it working without AltGR?

Comment: There are hacks for it, see the comments on [this idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/7603/).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!! ç Ç  : )

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen so far, but unfortunately it prevents `AltGr` from working as a modifier, so the combinations like `AltGr+Enter` don't work anymore. :(  The same downside as with mapping `AltGr` to [Compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey).

Answer (score 5):

I found this [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1075992/cedilla-under-c-%C3%A7-in-us-international-with-dead-keys-keyboard-layout-in-linu#1235405) which worked for me on Ubuntu 18:

> It's because the cedilla module isn't loaded by default when the
>   locale is set to *en*, so you have to change the configuration files
>   for gtk to add them:
>
> **1. Edit configuration files:**
>
> ```
> sudo vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache
>
> sudo vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
> ```
>
> On both, find the lines starting with `"cedilla" "Cedilla"` and add
>   :en to the line. Something like this:
>
> `"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk30" "/usr/share/locale"
>   "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"`
>
> **2. Change the Compose file:**
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose -e 's/ć/ç/g' -e 's/Ć/Ç/g'
> ```
>
> **3. Instruct the system to load the *cedilla* module:**
>
> Add those lines to `/etc/environment`:
>
> ```
> GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
> QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
> ```
>
> Reboot and you are done.

After doing this you will be able to do `' + c` and get a ç/cedilla

Comment: works perfectly

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 4):

At a glance, these layouts all appear to have keys for typing `ç`:

```
$ sgrep -o '%r\n' '"\"" _quote_ "\"" in ("name[Group1]" .. "\n" in outer("{" .. "}" containing "ccedilla"))' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/??
Andorra
Albania
Azerbaijan
Belgium
Brazil
Brazil - Eliminate dead keys
Brazil
Brazil - Dvorak
Brazil - Nativo
Brazil - Nativo for USA keyboards
Brazil - Nativo for Esperanto
Canada - French (legacy)
Canada - Multilingual, first part
Canada - Multilingual
Congo, Democratic Republic of the
Switzerland
Switzerland - German (Macintosh)
Czechia - UCW layout (accented letters only)
Spain
Spain - Eliminate dead keys
Spain - Dvorak
France
France - Bepo, ergonomic, Dvorak way
France - Breton
France - Macintosh
United Kingdom - Extended - Winkeys
Ghana - Fula
Iran - Kurdish, Arabic-Latin
Iceland
Iceland - Macintosh
Italy
Italy - Eliminate dead keys
Italy - Macintosh
Italy - Georgian
Nigeria - Hausa
Norway - Dvorak
Norway - Northern Saami
Portugal
Portugal - Eliminate dead keys
Portugal - Nativo
Portugal - Nativo for USA keyboards
Portugal - Nativo for Esperanto
Russia - Chuvash
Russia - Chuvash Latin
Senegal
Turkmenistan
Turkmenistan - Alt-Q
Turkey
Turkey - (F)
Turkey - International (with dead keys)
Turkey
Taiwan
USA - International (with dead keys)
USA - Dvorak international
USA - Programmer Dvorak
USA - Macintosh
USA - Colemak
```

Answer (score 2):

Brazil or us_intl, where you can do ' + c if language is set to portuguese (brazil)

Comment: I wish there was a way to use ' + c without changing language. For a clean install (en_US), just setting keyboard to Brazil still gives me `ć`. Also tried USA International (both AltGR and "dead keys"), same result. I could only get `ç` using AltGr + ","

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using another Linux distribution, and I initially used Jhuliano Moreno's solution (thanks, Jhuliano). However, after an update, it stopped working for me. So, I discovered a way to make it work consistently even after updates. (I tested this on Ubuntu, and it worked.)

Open your terminal and run the following command to copy the Compose file:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose
```

Next, use the following command to make necessary substitutions in the ~/.XCompose file:

```
sudo sed -i ~/.XCompose -e 's/ć/ç/g' -e 's/Ć/Ç/g'
```

After completing these steps, you can reboot your system.

Now, you should be able to use the ' + c combination to produce the desired character: ç.

Please note that I never encountered the same issue on Ubuntu because if you go to the 'Region & Language' settings and ensure that your format is set to 'Brasil,' it should work correctly without the need for manual configuration.

Settings -> Region & Language -> Formats:

[image: Formats, "Region & Language"]

Answer (score 1):

You can change your keyboard to English (US, international with dead keys) as said in this question:
[Can't write accent characters in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585600/cant-write-accent-characters-in-ubuntu-14-04)

With this change letters with accents **(á, é, ú, ô, ã)** will work except **ç**. You will need to change your system language to Portugue(Brazil) or you won't be able to write **ç**.

Answer (score 0):

The Portuguese layout allows you to type this character.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://github.com/marcopaganini/gnome-cedilla-fix

With this your are able to type cedilha without having to change the input method.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy! Just go to: System settings --> Keyboard Layout --> English (US, alternative international). This should be your layout. For some test try: ç = ' + c â é à...

Comment: As the OP said in his question, `c + '` results in `ć` in English( US, alternative international)