# How to configure English keyboard for Brazilian users to have cedilha character

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I can't type the *[c-cedilha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87)* character "ç" anymore expect in Sublime Text. The default key combination (' + c) is giving the character "ć".

How can I fix this?

I am currently Ubuntu 17.10 (with Gnome) and the "Input Sources" is set with *English (US, alternative international)*. This has always worked but it does not work anymore.

Using Dell XPS 15 (9550).

Edit: English (US, international with dead keys) has the same behavior.

This did't help to fix:
[What keyboard layout allows me to type ç?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30655/what-keyboard-layout-allows-me-to-type-%C3%A7)

Comment: the `us(alt-intl)` XKB layout should include a `dead_cedilla` deadkey on the level3 of `,` (comma), and should put `AltGr` on your Right Alt key.  does `AltGr+,` followed by `c` produce `ç`?  if you have a `Compose` key set, `Compose+,` followed by `c` should also produce `ç`.

Comment: Can you please choose *Ubuntu on Xorg* at login, and let us know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my earlier answer to a similar question:-

Press whatever you have set as the compose key then <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> in sequence will produce æ

This solution is much simpler, as you don't have to know the unicode for the character you wish to type. So, for example, press compose key then  <kbd>o</kbd>  then <kbd>e</kbd> will produce œ. compose key then <kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) will produce ç and so on.

I use the Right Windows key as the compose key as it isn't really used in the context of typing characters in Ubuntu.

If you don't already know, you can set the Compose Key by going to System Settings>Keyboard>Typing>Compose Key

Comment: In addition to this, it is recommended that you also configure the keyboard as international with dead keys, so the special letters with accents we have can be done. Without this layout, these characters will appear immediately.

Comment: Good to know that the problem is just the order of the keys. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Graham, sorry I'm new to this, and having the same problem, I've set my keyboard to US intl with dead key, and it worked to type (' + c) is giving the character "ç", today I noticed it's not working any longer, not sure what happened (installed few apps, not sure if it affected this behavior). I tried your solution but there's no Compose Key under Typing, I have only two choices: Switch to next input source and Switch to previous input source. Could you please detail more about how to set the Compose Key in Ubuntu 18.04? TIA

Comment: @Michael My answer was based on Ubuntu 16.04. For 18.04, you should consider this accepted response from Pomsky to a question about that version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028957/how-to-set-a-compose-key-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04 guys, the fix was released and it is coming in a few weeks. If you are using pre-releases upgrades, you can use it today. The issue was for any keyboard language happening when using not the primary language. Since my second keyboard language is Pt-Br

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Settings->Regions & Language
2) Set Language Portugues (Brasil); if English, cedilha will not work, but it works with French;
3) Set Format: Brasil
4) Sources of input: English (United States), then choose English (USA, inter. alt. with dead keys)
5) Remove other input sources

By doing this, I had to reconfigure my multiple displays. Just took them out, restarted, and repluged them.

Comment: On Kubuntu 20.04, System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Layouts, I set the English (US) layout and English (US, intl., with dead keys) variant