# How to type ñ (enye / enie) letter on QWERTY on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 19.04

How should I type the ñ ([Spanish eñe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91)) letter on an English QWERTY Keyboard on Kubuntu 19.04?

Comment: If it's an answer, you should post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What keyboard layout allows me to type ç?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30655/what-keyboard-layout-allows-me-to-type-%c3%a7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **English (US, intl, with dead keys)** (`us+intl`) as an [input source on KDE settings](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching#KDE4_.2F_Plasma). On GNOME it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Then type **ñ** with <kbd>AltGr + n</kbd>. Same thing for áéíóú (acute accents). Use the y for the ü ([umlaut/dieresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))).

[Here](https://www.csbsju.edu/Documents/MCL/resource/use-int-keyboard.pdf) and [here](https://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html) you'll find more:

[image: keyboard layout]

**Note**: You can switch between your input sources with <kbd>Super + space</kbd>

For a terminal way take a look to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/435243/349837)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open `Keyboard` app from System Settings module
2. Go to `Layouts` tab
3. Click on `Configure layouts`
4. Click `Add`
   4.a `Limit selection by language` set `English`
   4.b `Layout` set `EurKey (US based layout with European letters)`
5. Remove default layout so you end up with only the EurKey layout
6. Click on `Apply` and test, you should be able to type `ñ` pressing <kbd>right-Alt` + n</kbd>.
7. You can get `áéíóú` by pressing <kbd>right-Alt + '</kbd> and then pressing the vowel.

I hope it helps!.

Comment: This isn't the best solution. The proper way is with the US International, "dead keys" variant.

Comment: Thank you! could you please add it as an answer to accept it?