# Just upgraded to 20.04.1 LTS and some accentuation is gone

Tags: keyboard

I use english and portuguese (pt-br), my keyboard is USA design, so it is configured english-international (with dead keys)
I used this for many years.
The new-installed 20.04.1 LTS does not allow me to reach C-cedilla.
The key map shows it, but is not functioning.
All other accentuations are appearently functioning.
Checking the characters application, I notice, "single comma + c" should return "unicode U+00E7" but it is returning "unicode U+0107" instead.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, usually `GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla` works, but not this time.

Comment: Other answers in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30655/what-keyboard-layout-allows-me-to-type-%c3%a7/1113491#1113491

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1235405/98798

Basically, you need to tell gtk config files is not loading the cedilla module when using the English locale.

So we change the gtk files to tell it to do it, with these two commands:

```
sudo sed -i '/^"cedilla/ { s/" $/:en"/; }' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache
sudo sed -i '/^"cedilla/ { s/" $/:en"/; }' /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

And make sure you have these two lines in `/etc/environment`:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```